# Python coding error

Tags: python, python-3.x

*I am pretty new to the python programming language and I was deciding to learn it by practising therefore I'd ask you that any sort of answer, please be as simple as possible because*.
I am trying to create an app which gives **tells you if you're overweight or lowerweight** through a mathematic equation. But not knowing what I'm doing through the process I've got the error that tkinter libraries are missing. The code I currently have you can find [here](http://pasted.co/d3229dcc)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's/where's the error?

Comment: I think the error is that you misspelled "shitt".

Comment: which line?sorry cant find it

Comment: Can you show what `e.info()` returns ? also you are increasing `info[]` (whatever that is) but is checking `personWeight`?

Comment: Lol sorry but i did mention im pretty new to python...What i want to do is create a textbox gui...get the input from that and save it to a variable called info...than i want to split the informatuion from info to 2 other variables...than i will use the information on those 2 variables in the equation ive done.

Comment: `info[:2] += personsWeight` is putting `personsWeight`'s value into `info[]` which is not what you want based on what you are describing, But your error is referring to you using an int where it should be a str type. My guess is `info` is a string but you are trying to add an int to a str which doesn't work. you have to cast the types to make them the same. Once again can you provide what `info` holds?

Comment: Do you bother just rewriting that part of code and pasting it here please...it would really help me way more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.get()` is returning a string. The line `info[:2] += personsWeight` is failing because you are attempting to add an `int` (personsWeight) to a `str`, which will attempt a string concatenation, but fail due to the type incompatibility.

It seems like you want the user to input their weight and then their height in the box. Something like this "150 72". Is this correct?

If so, you should split the input using the `split()` method for strings and then convert into floats

```
# split the string at the space and convert to int
weight, height = [info.split() # weight = "150", height = "72"

# convert from string to float
weight = float(weight)  # weight = 150.0
height = float(height)  # height = 72.0
```

You can do this as a one-liner also:

```
weight, height = [float(v) for v in info.split()]
```

You may want to review this [page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings#Variables) for some more information about setting variables. It also has a section on [combining numbers and strings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings#Combining_Numbers_and_Strings) which is relevant to the error you're seeing.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if it solved your problem! :D